# How to access to all viewmodels via the viewmodel base?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I've created a ViewModel class that have inside the implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged, now I also have other ViewModels that inherit from the ViewModel (base). 
All working good actually but I have a doubt.
So let's say that I've in the CustomerViewModel an ObservableCollection called Price, like this:

```
private ObservableCollection<Models.Price> _price = new ObservableCollection<Models.Price>();
public ObservableCollection<Models.Price> Price
{
     get { return _price; }
}
```

this ObservableCollection should be populated by other classes, 'cause I need to access to the same resource.

I really don't understand how can I do this in mvvm. I though to a Singleton ViewModel, so something like this defined in the base VM:

```
 public static ViewModel Instance { get; set; }
```

So import all the childs VM into the base and access them via ViewModel.Instance.Price;

but doesn't seems a good practice for me. Any idea?

Comment: Where does your Prices come from? If Database, think about implementing a RepositotyPattern and make your Repository a Singleton

Comment: @lokusking No database. Simply data populate behind code

Comment: Then make your Generator auch singleton

Comment: @lokusking but I can't understand how can I access from base viewModel the properties of CustomerViewModel by ViewModel.Instance.Price

Comment: The idea behind is, that you have a single global class from where you get access to your generated objects

Comment: so? could you provide a simple example? @lokusking

Comment: If you feel that my answer helped you, you could [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this implementation, you can share the same Datasource to all ViewModels

```
public class PriceGenerator {

        private PriceGenerator() {
            this.Prices = new ObservableCollection<Price>();
            this.Generate();

        }

        void Generate() {
            //Generate Objects here

            this.Prices.Add(generatedPrice);
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Price> Prices {
            get;
        }


        private static PriceGenerator _instance;
        public static PriceGenerator Instance => _instance ?? (_instance = new PriceGenerator());

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are generally two approaches to this.

1. Even if you don't have a real database/repository, implement a singleton class that simulates this. This singleton class should also implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` (and/or `INotifyCollectionChanged` as appropriate). All ViewModels will be able to access this simulated repository, and interested ViewModels can choose to subscribe to this repository's `PropertyChanged` callback. For your question, it is generally tidier to have a repository that handles **just** prices, rather than having a simulated repository that stores 101 different information.
2. Have a main ViewModel. Some people would visualize that the `MainWindow` being the main view, with a corresponding main ViewModel. This ViewModel is intentionally made a singleton, which other ViewModels can access through static call. This main ViewModel is basically acting just like #1 - it is like a repository that stores 101 different information. That main ViewModel is likely to look untidy, but it is simply to trace where things are stored - if you need any data, it's probably in there.

Personally, I prefer to use the first approach. [lokusking's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38041351/2970960) is an example of this approach. Although his "repository" does more than storing data.